# How can I export data from an Excel worksheet into a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I am trying to take data that has been saved in an excel sheet and use it to populate a website. I want to create an automated process that takes specific cells or rows and uses them to populate divs and unordered lists. Everything I've found is about doing the opposite: taking tables in HTML and using them to populate excel sheets. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

By saving the file as a .csv in Excel you can certainly parse the data so that can be manipulated and formatted in a HTML website, http://papaparse.com/ is a good library for parsing the data